# How to overcome the error in println zoo in java

Tags: java

i have checked several post regarding the way of making print out but couldn't find the one that can solve my problem.
so i needed to create a zoo with some animals inside in java, so i did several steps. I started with main class Animal:

Animal.java

```
public class Animal {

    public static String name;
    public static String species;
    public static int age;
    Animal(){

    }

    public Animal(String name, String species, int age) {
        Animal.name=name;
        Animal.species=species;
        Animal.age=age;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    private static void printInfo() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Age:"+age +", Species: " + species);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

than subclasses:

```
Elephant.java:

public class Elephant extends Animal {

    public Elephant() {
    }
    Elephant(String name, int age, String species) {
        super(name, species, age);



        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Lion.java:

```
public class Lion extends Animal {


    public Lion() {

    }
        Lion(String name, int age, String species) {
            super(name, species, age);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Panda.java:

```
public class Panda extends Animal {


    public Panda() {

    }
        Panda(String name, int age, String species) {
            super(name, species, age);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

and subclasses of the subclasses:
Child1. java

```
public class ElleElephantChild extends Elephant {

    public ElleElephantChild() {
    }
    ElleElephantChild(String name, int age, String species){
        Animal.name = "Elle";
        Animal.age=0;
        Animal.species=species;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Child2.java:

```
public class SpotPandaChild extends Panda {

    public SpotPandaChild() {
    }
    SpotPandaChild(String name, int age, String species){
        Animal.name = "Spot";
        Animal.age=0;
        Animal.species=species;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

So im trying to print out in Animal class information:
name, species and age.
but getting this error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class Animal, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

i think im missing main point, anyone could help? thank you

Comment: It looks fine to me. Try restarting your ide

Comment: First, the fields you have in `Animal` should *not* be static, and should *not* be prefixed with the word `Animal`. Second, you don't create individual animals by subclassing the animal class, but by creating an *instance* of it using `new`. Third, you didn't put anything in your `main` method. Please review your textbook.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i have tried not to use static word in my previous attempts but the program automatically declaring it as an error, and keep requesting to use it. for second point i understood and will correct it! third the main() im using in next step Zoobuilder. at this stage im just trying to print out animals and see the output, thank you!

Comment: I suggest that you read up on some basics of object-oriented programming, and Java programming in general because you seem to be thoroughly missing the point

Comment: @user9791370 anything in particular you can suggest? i will definitely do so, as i took this course and they had 0 explanation in the java but just throw you a task!

Comment: I just wrote a brief summary as an answer, let me know if you think it helps

Comment: The program was complaining about not using station because you were using the variables from a static method - e.g. your printinfo method - it shouldn't be static, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how I might implement something like this:

```
public class Animal {

public String name; //not static!Static means that one variable is shared among all instances of a class, which is not what you want here presumably
public String species;
public int age;

public Animal(String name, String species, int age) { //this is okay
    this.name=name;
    this.species=species;
    this.age=age;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
Animal thisAnimal = new Animal("Hungry Hippo", "Hippopotamus", 5);

//thisAnimal is an INSTANCE of the animal class, and will be created when you run the program. (whatever is in your main method is what gets run.) 
}
}
```

If you want to create animals that EXTEND the Animal class:

```
public class Panda extends Animal {



  public Panda(String name, int age, String species) {
        super(name, species, age);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}
Then, rather than creating a SpotPandaChild class, you want to create a Panda OBJECT that is an instance of the Panda class, and is called SpotPandaChild:
Ex. Inside your main method:

```
  Panda SpotPandaChild = new Panda("Spot", 0, "Pandaus Nonhumanus");
```

I hope this clarified things for you a little bit!

Comment: Yes! thank you so much, i can see the errors i have made! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the helpful comments and feedback! i fixed it and its working.